# How To Create Dynamic Stream Listeners in Spring Cloud Stream Kafka?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka. I have StreamListeners for topics that are predefined. My new requirement is to create and stop StreamListeners runtime for a user defined topic name. So from user interface user will determine and update which topic names will be listened and with topic listeners (StreamListeners) will be stopped. Is there any way to have flexible StreamListeners runtime?
I tried to use BinderAwareChannelResolver, but while setting different binders to different bindings I get UnknownBinder Configuration Error. I could not find a detailed example covering my requirements using BinderAwareChannelResolver.

```
@Autowired
private SubscribableChannelBindingTargetFactory bindingTargetFactory;

@Autowired
private BindingService bindingService;

@Autowired
BinderFactory binderFactory;

BindingServiceProperties properties = bindingService.getBindingServiceProperties();
properties.getConsumerProperties(channelName ).setBatchMode(true);

String binderConfigurationName = properties.getBinder(channelName);
Binder<SubscribableChannel, ConsumerProperties, ?> binder = (Binder<SubscribableChannel, ConsumerProperties, ?>) binderFactory.getBinder(binderConfigurationName, channel.getClass());
    copyExtendedConsumerProperties(binder, channelName);

bindingService.bindConsumer(channel, channelName);
channel.subscribe(new DynamicMessageHandler());

private void copyExtendedConsumerProperties(Binder binder, String channelName) {
    KafkaConsumerProperties extension = (KafkaConsumerProperties) ((ExtendedPropertiesBinder) binder).getExtendedConsumerProperties(channelName);
    extension.getConfiguration().put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, PersonDeserializer.class.getName());
    extension.getConfiguration().put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "3000");
    extension.getConfiguration().put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, "900000");
    extension.getConfiguration().put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, "5000");
    extension.getConfiguration().put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
}

public class DynamicMessageHandler implements MessageHandler {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
    List<Person> personList = (List<Person>) message.getPayload();
    System.out.println(personList.size());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of two `StreamListener` methods in which both of them are stopped at application startup.

```
@Autowired
BindingsEndpoint endpoint;

@StreamListener("input-1")
public void listen1(String in) {
 System.out.println();
}

@StreamListener("input-2")
public void listen2(String in) {
 System.out.println();
}

@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner() {
  return args -> {
     endpoint.changeState("input-1", State.STOPPED);
     endpoint.changeState("input-1", State.STOPPED);
}
```

When you run this application, it starts with both `StreamListener`s stopped. Now the user interface you mentioned need to expose the binding names. From the interface, the user will select, let's say, `input-1` to start. Then the `StreamListener` named as `listen1` will be started and the other one (`listen2`) will remain stopped. You can implement a REST endpoint to pass the binding name so that the binding can be started using the `BindingsEndpoint`.

`BinderAwareChannelResolver` is meant for dynamic destinations and used for outbound purposes. Not sure, how it can be helpful for your use case. In any case, `BinderAwareChannelResolver`, is deprecated in the latest versions of Spring Cloud Stream.

Spring Cloud Stream starting with 3.0.x versions, mainly prefers processors and consumers with a functional style. Although `StreamListener` is still available in 3.0.x, starting with 3.1.x, its usage is deprecated. We suggest you update your `StreamListener` methods to a functional style.

The two `StreamListener` methods above can be re-written as below:

```
@Bean
public Consumer<String> listen1() {
  return s -> {};
}

@Bean
public Consumer<String> listen2() {
  return s -> {};
}
```

By default, the binding names will be `listen1-in-0` and `listen2-in-0` which you can change. See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_programming_model).

Comment: My requirements are;
 - My topic names and topic count will be determined runtime and will be user defined, 
 this topic names and topic count may change any time during my application lifecycle.
 So I don't have a chance to have predefined StreamListeners initially. 
 - I want to be able to dynamically set the broker addresses at runtime.
 - I want to dynamically set different binders to different bindings. 
 - I want to be able to configure consumer to consume data as batch. 
 - I want to give the partition number from producer side at runtime. @sobychacko

Comment: I tried to make such changes myself, but I don't know if I did it right. 
I edited my question and put a code sample. Can you review?
I would be glad if you could guide me in this regard. @sobychacko

Comment: You probably have to use what is detailed here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_spring_cloud_stream_sendto_destination

Comment: Basically, each time the topic is changed, you can represent that through the `sendto.destination` header. In any case, these requirements are not very trivial and need more customization.